# Trying to download ~200 files using ThreadPoolExecutor -> some files are skipped

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, download, python-multithreading

I need to download ~200 files. If I run code below for the 1st time, the code downloads ~100 files. Then I need to run this code few more times in order to download the rest files (ie. if I run the code 2nd time - I can get +20-30 new files, if 3rd time - again +20-30, and so on). Why does this happen\how to fix? Maybe this is important - server may generate some files up to 10 sec.

```
import os
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request
import shutil

def get_cities(osm_id, file_name, place_type):
    file_folder = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), place_type)
    file_name = file_name + '_' + place_type
    file_path = os.path.join(file_folder, file_name)

    if not os.path.exists(file_folder):
        os.makedirs(file_folder)

    if not os.path.exists(file_path):
        area_id = str(3600000000 + osm_id)

        url = 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=(node["place"="city"](area:'+area_id+'););out;'

        with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(file_path, 'wb') as out_file:
            shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)

def cities_controller(place_type='cities'):
    countries = Countries.objects.filter(status=1).exclude(osm_id=None)
    en_group_inst = Languages.objects.filter(iso_code='en').first().group

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as executor:
        for country in countries:
            osm_id = country.osm_id
            file_name = CountriesTranslations.objects.get(
                country=country, lang_group=en_group_inst).common_name.lower().replace(' ', '_')

            executor.submit(get_cities, osm_id, file_name, place_type)

cities_controller()
```

Comment: Have you checked if you got any `URLError` or `HTTPError` exception?

Comment: There is no any errors, unfortunately

Comment: I use a custom thread pool using `threading` module and `queue.Queue` and never faced such issues. I usually go for 800+ pages. This is not to say that `ThreadPoolExecutor` is at fault. I wanted to know if any thread died. put the `urlopen` in a `try/ except`. catch all `Exception`.

Comment: Once you asked about any exceptions, I re-checked using `try\except` :) - no errors. Just tried to change `with urilib.requests.urlopen(url) ...` part to `r = requests.get(url); with open(file_path, "wb") as out_file: out_file.write(r.content)` and code started to work as expected. Strange. Could be any problems with urllib?...

Comment: That's strange, I always use `urllib`. For the last time, do without `shutil`. Just `.write` it as you have done here.